# Trying to access a internal modem over serial with putty. Only typing letters a and A work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, putty, modem

I try to connect to an internal broadband modem over the serial (com port) with putty.
It is Windows 7 64 with 64 bit drivers for the modem. When I connect with putty to the port the only letters I can enter are a and A. No other letters work, enter does not work either.

I thought it might be a problem because of 64 bit drivers, and also tried with putty 64 bit. did not help either. I also tried to edit the putty source code and tried a few things, but that did not help. Increasing the timeouts made it easier to enter the "a","A"s though, before that sometimes not even a worked. Also tried with Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection .. did not help either.

If I access the com port with windows powershell, it looks like it is more or less working. I can send commands, and mostly get answers. I used the following code for that which I found online:

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM6,115200,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.WriteLine('at+csq' + '`r')
start-sleep -m 50
$port.ReadExisting()
$port.Close()
```

I also tried with hyper terminal and with tera term. Same problem. The modem looks like it is working though. and some applications can access it without any problem (for example gammu 64bit)

tl;dr: Trying to use putty to connect to com6: port on windows 7 64bit. While com6: is the serial port of a wwan modem with 64 bit drivers (Option N.V. GTM382 W with latest drivers).

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between SE sites.  Pick a site and close it at the other one.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 deleted on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by the way. I made a very stupid mistake. Echo was off at the modem ...

I managed to turn it on using:

```
 ATE1
```